# Making player character behave as if using mouse events Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game that has a player ship hovering a fixed distance over a tower defense grid. I'd like the tile beneath the ship to highlight when the ship is over it. By using the OnMouseOver() function, this is quite easy, however, I do not want this to be controlled by the mouse but by the player ship. Is there a way to pass mouse event simulations to a game object? How would i go about assigning this function to the ship?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`OnTriggerStay()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)

Answer (score 2):

Like derHugo siad you can use `OnTriggerStay()`. Altough you can also use a raycast to check if something is underneath the ship:

```
    public void FixedUpdate()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out hit, 10f))
    {
        //Here obj will be filled with the gameobject under your ship. You can use this to check for the tag, get components and outline the object.
        var obj = hit.transform.gameObject;
    }
}
```

Hope this sets you into the right direction.